# Kotlin use block function is not called on File.printWriter()

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and I'm trying to do a simple task - create and write to a file. For some reason, using `use()` with a block function on `printWriter()` doesn't actually write.

```
    File("test2.txt").printWriter().use { out ->
        {
            println("hmmm")
            out.println("what's up")
            log.info { "finished writing" }
        }
    }
```

In fact, the block function doesn't seem to be called at all - both "hmmm" and "finished writing" never show up, although the file itself is created (but is totally empty).

The much simpler `writeText()` works just fine - the file is created and the given text is written to the file.

```
    File("test3.txt").writeText("testing")
```

What am I doing wrong in my `use()` version?

**Edit**: it seems to be a syntax issue with my block function. Looks like I have an extra pair of brackets? Would love a brief explanation as to why it makes it not work.

**Edit 2**: I think I understand now. The way I wrote it, I was essentially returning the block function itself rather than running through it.

Comment: Suggestion: now that you solved it, write your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

So the problem was that the way I was writing the block function caused it to just return the inner block function, and not actually call it.

Here are two ways that work:

```
    File("test2.txt").printWriter().use {
        println("hmmm")
        it.println("what's up")
        log.info { "finished writing!" }
    }

    File("test2.txt").printWriter().use(fun(out) {
        println("hmmm")
        out.println("what's up")
        log.info { "finished writing!" }
    })
```

Although, for my purposes `writeText()` actually works just fine and is much shorter haha.